# Validating a form created via php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have a PHP form.

The form elements are created based off the user's selection which is in a dropdown menu.

What I am trying to accomplish is loop through that form and validate the values of two elements with the id's of "action" and "amt".

Now, I should mention the form which I am trying to validate can have x amount of elements because it needs to be based on the users needs. When I call my validate function it does check the id's and alerts the value, however, it alerts the value of the first input element with the id "amt" three/multiple times.

This is bad as because I need to perform some computation and the duplicate entries would cause an error in the the computation.

Here is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){
    var i;
    var passtest = 0;
    var test = "";
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    alert("Enter function");
    for(  i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
    if(form.elements[i].id === "action" && form.elements[i].value ===   "Debit" ||  form.elements[i].value === "Credit"){
        test = form.elements[i].value;
        // Alerts action
        alert(test);
        if(document.getElementById("amt").value !=""){

            // Get the value from the input element id amt
            test = document.getElementById("amt").value;

            // Alerts value from id amt
            alert(test);
            //passtest = 1;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("amtTD").innerHTML = "Check   Amounts";
            return false;
        }
        alert("End of if stmt");    
    }
    else{
        // If it is not id action or id amt just Alert value if any
        test = form.elements[i].value;
        alert(test);
    }
   }

   ///******    END OF FOR LOOP ******   ///
   if(passtest === 1){
    return true;
   }
   else{
   alert("Submission failed");
   return false;
   }
 }

</script>
```

Here Is the php code that which displays the form

```
<form name='transaction' id="myForm" onsubmit="return validate()" action='' method='post'>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
if (isset($_POST['acctN'])) {
echo "<table class='table' id='myRow'' style=''>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Account Name</th>";
echo "<th>Action</th>";
echo "<th>Amount</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
foreach ($_POST['acctN'] as $name) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM ChartOfAccounts WHERE AccountName = '$name'";
$results = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($cxn));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
echo "<tbody>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class ='col-md-6'><select name='account[]' class='form-control' style=''><option>" . $row['AccountName'] . "</option></select></td>";
echo "<td class ='col-md-2'><select name='debOrCred[]' id='action' class='form-control' style=''>
<option value='Debit'>Debit</option>
<option value='Credit'>Credit</option>
</select></td>";
echo "<td class ='col-md-2'> <input type='text' name='amount[]' class='form-control' id='amt' style=''/> <span id ='amtTD' style='color:red;'> </span></td>";
echo "<td class ='col-sm-2'>$</td>";
echo "<td class ='col-sm-2'><button type='button' onclick='removeCell()' class='btn btn-danger'value='Remove' name='".$row['AccountName']."'>Remove</button></td>";
echo "</tr>";       
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
}
echo "<label style='margin-left:7px;'>Documentation</label>";
echo "<textarea name='src-doc' class='form-control' rows ='4' cols='50' placeholder='Description' style='max-width:575px; margin-left:8px;' ></textarea>";
echo "<div style='padding:10px;'>";
echo "<label>Source</label>";
echo "<input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Submit' name='subTrans' style='margin-top:7px; margin-left:8px; '/>";     
}                   
?>
</form>
```

Thank you all that help and provide input.

Comment: Seems like you are outputting multiple fields with the exact same ID.  ID must be unique in a document.  When you call document.getElementById it will correctly return the first element with the given ID.

Comment: @James I tried selecting by name and the script fails.